# JavaScript function on event running on declaration

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling

Why when i load page it runs function and alerts me "function run" i did not call it nowhere i need function to only trigger on element click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

open_close = function() {
   alert("function run");
   //some code ...
}

window.onload = function() {
   //some code ...
   var myButton = document.getElementById('button');
   myButton.onclick = open_close();
   //some code ...
}

</script>
```

Here's jfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/ayeBP/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, but you *did* run it:

```
myButton.onclick = open_close();
```

**Parentheses invoke a function.** Use this instead:

```
myButton.onclick = open_close;
```

[Better still (click through for legacy IE support):](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

```
myButton.addEventListener('click', open_close);
```

---

> Okay this was simplidied function i need to actually pass 2 variables to it e.g. `myButton.onclick = open_close(var1,var2);`

You *still* cannot use parentheses as you keep trying to do, because parentheses invoke the function. Use an anonymous function:

```
myButton.onclick = function () {
    open_close(var1, var2);
};

// or, even better,
myButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    open_close(var1, var2);
});
```

Comment: that's why jQuery is always a better way to this kind of stuff in IE~ `$("myButton").on("click",open_close);`

Comment: Okay this was simplidied function i need to actually pass 2 variables to it e.g. `myButton.onclick = open_close(var1,var2);`

I know someone will mention jquerry i just knew it...

Comment: @redacted look, you used parentheses _again_. You can't do that, because it invokes the function. Editing...

Comment: @redacted see my edit. But seriously, what's your reason for not using some sort of cross-browser library? If you loathe jQuery and the fanboys (myself included) there are plenty others to choose from.

Comment: Actually `myButton.onclick = open_close;` worked even on IE 6.0 i just checked on virtual PC so i don't see problem there.

Reason is i like to have pure code that i wrote and no extra files to download. I am minimalist i guess.

Comment: @redacted [it's not a matter of compatibility.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener.3F)

Comment: The important thing was the ability to store the function outside the code that executes it because function is big and code inside window.onload loops too many times... guess that's impossible.

Comment: I actually thought of this and it works,
   `myButton.onclick = function() {
        open_close(var1,var2);
       }`
` this way it can exec function on click which calls another function. What do you think.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `open_close()` with `open_close`

Using parentheses here will invoke the function immediately and assign the return value of it to `myButton.onclick`

Comment: Okay this was simplidied function i need to actually pass 2 variables to it e.g. `myButton.onclick = open_close(var1,var2);`